# How to input integers into a vector<int> that is empty?

Tags: c++, loops, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> ivec;
    int n = 4;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator iter = ivec.begin(); iter != ivec.begin() + n; ++iter) {
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        ivec.push_back(x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Above is the code.

What I want is to experiment with inputting 4 integers into an empty vector.

The result is it compiles and runs but never jumps out of the loop whatever I type.

I made some adjustments.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> ivec;
    int n = 4;
    std::vector<int>::iterator tempiter = ivec.begin();
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator iter = tempiter; iter != tempiter + n; ++iter) {
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        ivec.push_back(x);
    }
    std::cout << "**********************************" << std::endl;

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator iter = ivec.begin(); iter != ivec.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This time it works fine as expected.

I ivec.begin() should always stay the same.

Why doesn't it work the first time ?
Why does it work the second time?

I think there is not much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three reasons:

1. Invalidation: `std::vector` sometimes reallocates itself, and when it does, all the iterators are invalidated. Since you don't know when reallocations happen, you should assume iterator is invalidated after each insertion.
2. Access violation: `iter + n` returns an element that is after the last, and thus might cause an access violation when dereferencing, so should be avoided.
3. The loop is infinite, because ivec.begin() is calculated again and again, and the original iter was behind in the memory. This is an implementation detail, and thus this might not lead to an infinite loop in another machine.

Given my answer, your second code should not work as well, and if it does, it's by chance.

Correct way to do this is without iterators:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> ivec;
    int n = 4;
    // consider writing ivec.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        ivec.push_back(x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `iter + n` does not returns an element, it is just an iterator and here is not access violation until somebody try to dereference that iterator

Comment: new begin() may be in any memory place, old begin() value may be behind and may be not behind new one in memory

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that iterator keeps same value when you modify `std::vector`. Iterator points to internal memory block that stores `std::vector` values. When you push item and there is no place for it, entire block is reallocated, old elements are copied into new block and new element inserted at the end. Since this moment begin iterator points to the beginnig of new block and its old value became invalid. You should not use `std::vector` iterators in this way, rather use total elements count in vector:

```
for (; ivec.size() < n; )
{
    ...
}
```